# Not able to create subdomain from goDaddy

Tags: subdomain, godaddy

I have this domain iarmar.com hosted in goDaddy and as my web server is with another host i am using host @ record to point it to my server. my webserver is powered by CentOS and Cpanel11. i tried creating godaddy from both goDaddy and cPanel although in both records get created but it won't work for example in goDaddy i went to.

```
Domain Manager > Forward Subdomains > Manage > Add Subdomain
```

and created the record there, below is the screenshot of the record i created in godaddy.

[image: Godaddy Screenshot]

this doesn't work, as i am unable to access the subdomain even after i created it. i tried through cPanel too but there too it won't work. is there something more record i should be changing like something in DNS manager of godaddy?

thanks.

Comment: How long are you waiting to test the forward? sometimes DNS changes take a few minutes to propagate. In fact, that forward worked just fine for me.

Comment: are you sure, it worked fine for you, because it is still not working for me :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I check your DNS server the SOA record shows cache timeouts set for 2 hours... but when I check individual records they are set to 1 hour.

You would need to wait at least 1 hour after a change to be sure that records have been updated...

Sometimes, if you are running windows, you can try "ipconfig /flushdns" in a command window and then reload the url. DNS servers cache data too so you may need flush the cache on your local DNS server as well, if you have one. Sometimes that helps, other times you can't get to the main server and all you can do is wait for the timeout of the cache to check the new DNS records.

> # dig iarmar.com soa
>
> ; <<>> DiG 9.4.2-P2 <<>> iarmar.com soa
>   ;; global options:  printcmd
>   ;; Got answer:
>   ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 63713
>   ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 0
>
> ;; QUESTION SECTION:
>   ;iarmar.com.                    IN      SOA
>
> ;; ANSWER SECTION:
>   iarmar.com.             3600    IN      SOA     ns27.domaincontrol.com. dns.jomax.net. 2011082500 28800 7200 604800 86400
>
> ;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
>   iarmar.com.             3563    IN      NS      ns27.domaincontrol.com.
>   iarmar.com.             3563    IN      NS      ns28.domaincontrol.com.
>
> ;; Query time: 79 msec
>   ;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
>   ;; WHEN: Thu Aug 25 20:35:15 2011
>   ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 129